# Convergence in distribution on product space (definition)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, product-space

Let $S$ and $T$ be seperable metric spaces, $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a $S$-valued sequence of random variables and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a $T$-valued sequence of random variables

Is convergence in distribution **on a product space** defined by

$\mathbf{E}[f(X_n)g(Y_n)]\to\mathbf{E}[f(X)g(Y)]$

for all continuous, bounded functions $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$, $g:T\to\mathbb{R}$

?

Comment: My guess would be you might need some independence as a condition.

Comment: I would always use the definition of convergence in distribution as the CDF converging at all continuity points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we should consider $S \times T$ with corresponding metric and check the next condition:
$\mathbf{E}[f(X_n, Y_n)]\to\mathbf{E}[f(X, Y)]$.

Here we suppose that $(X_n, Y_n)$ are defined on one probability space $\Omega_n$. We have similar condition for $(X,Y)$.

Comment: So if i would consider $S\times T$ with a corresponding metric $d=d_s \times d_t$ and would check the condition, than i would have convergence in distribution on $S\times T$?

Comment: Do you maybe know if this is anywhere formalized in a book?

Comment: @toni_iva, yes. See Billingsley, "Convergence of probability measures" (in the beginning).